# Is a map iterator object in Python3.x can only be used once and why? (codes and examples attached)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mutable

With this code:

```
strs = ["111", "1000", "1000", "1000"]
# count the numbers of '0' and '1' respectively for each string in strs 
counts = map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs)

cntSortBy0 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[0])  # sort with counts of '0'

cntSortBy1 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort with counts of '1'
```

Here I have a list `strs` with strings as elements.

Then I count the numbers of '0' and '1' respectively for each string in strs and save the results in `counts` (I did this using map in python3, so `count` is a map object).

After that I sort `counts` for the first time, and it works fine,
but when I sort `counts` for the second time, it returns an empty list(`cntSortBy1` is empty),

I find that this is because `counts` became empty **after the first sort**:

```
>>> strs = ["111", "1000", "1000", "1000"]
>>>  counts = map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs)
>>> cntSortBy0 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[0])  # sort with counts of '0'
>>> list(counts)
[]
```

No wonder `cntSortBy1` is empty, but why dose this happen?

Besides, if I just merely print `list(counts)`, `cntSortBy1` will also became empty, as shown below,

```
>>> strs = ["111", "1000", "1000", "1000"]
>>> counts = map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs)
>>> list(counts)
[[0, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
>>> cntSortBy0 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[0])
>>> cntSortBy0
[]
```

- Dose this mean a map object could only be used once, after that it will become an empty list?
- Is there any other objects in Py3 with the same feature? (I have tried `range()`, it is not.)

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Instead of a map, you can try counts = [[x.count('0'), x.count('1')] for x in strs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an iterator has been exhausted (meaning, fully iterated over), there is nothing left to be iterated over, so iterating over it a second time won't yield anything. Take this example.

```
a = map(int,['1','2','3'])

for i in a:
    print(i)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

This will output:

```
1
2
3
```

Whenever you need to iterate over an iterator multiple times, turn it into a list (or another type of sequence):

```
a = list(map(int,['1','2','3']))
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

When using `sorted()`, you're also iterating over the `map` iterator object:

```
a = map(int,['1','2','3'])
print(sorted(a)) # output: [1, 2, 3]
print(sorted(a)) # output: []

a = list(map(int,['1','2','3']))
print(sorted(a)) # output: [1, 2, 3]
print(sorted(a)) # output: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python3 `map` returns an iterator:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

And iterators can (and should) be used only once. See official doc about iterators:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators

In your case you need to convert `map` to `list` upon creation, that'll solve your problem:

```
counts = list(map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs))
```

Comment: Which, to be honest, would be more Pythonic written like `counts = [[x.count('0'), x.count('1')] for x in strs]`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

> map(function, iterable, ...)
>   Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results.

What a map does is returns an iterator, which you can iterate on, but once you are done iterating on it, it becomes empty, or as you keep iterating on it, size of iterator keeps reducing

Hence when you done iterating over the iterator `counts` returned by `map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs)` via `sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[0])`, it becomes empty

To avoid this, you need to cast any iterator you want to reuse into a list using `list(map(...))` and then you can use it as much as you want, for example.

```
In [1]:  strs = ["111", "1000", "1000", "1000"]                                                                                                                                                   

In [2]: counts = list(map(lambda x: [x.count('0'), x.count('1')], strs))                                                                                                                          

In [3]: counts)                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[3]: [[0, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]

In [4]: cntSortBy0 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[0])                                                                                                                                           

In [5]: cntSortBy0                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[5]: [[0, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]

In [6]: counts                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[6]: [[0, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]

In [7]: cntSortBy1 = sorted(counts, key=lambda x: x[1])                                                                                                                                           

In [9]: cntSortBy1                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[9]: [[3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1], [0, 3]]

In [10]: counts                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[10]: [[0, 3], [3, 1], [3, 1], [3, 1]]
```

As you can see, we utilized `counts` twice, but it was never empties, since we now converted it to a list, which is intact even after you iterate on in countless number of times.